# More values in Ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I have a nav component set up to return different navigation set up for a user who is logged in and one who is logged in. I need to add one more for a user who is an admin.
I will have another const for administrators. How do I go about doing so?
 The ternary operator won't allow me to add another value as far as I know.

```
render() {

const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;

const notLoggedIn = (
  <div id='header'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <div id='logo' class='pull-left'>
        <h1>
          <Link className='scrollto' to='/'>
            The Sports Bet Leader
          </Link>{' '}
        </h1>
      </div>

      <nav id='nav-menu-container'>
        <button
          class='navbar-toggler'
          type='button'
          data-toggle='collapse'
          data-target='#navbarNav'
          aria-controls='navbarNav'
          aria-expanded='false'
          aria-label='Toggle navigation'
        >
          <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
        </button>
        <ul class='nav-menu'>
          <li class='menu-active'>
            <Link className='' to='/'>
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link className='' to='/register'>
              Register
            </Link>{' '}
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link className='' to='/login'>
              Login
            </Link>{' '}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
);

const loggedIn = (
  <div id='header'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <div id='logo' class='pull-left'>
        <h1>
          <Link className='scrollto' to='/'>
            The Sports Bet Leader
          </Link>{' '}
        </h1>
        {/* <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo --> */}
        {/* <a href="#intro"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" title="" /></a> */}
      </div>

      <nav id='nav-menu-container'>
        <button
          class='navbar-toggler'
          type='button'
          data-toggle='collapse'
          data-target='#navbarNav'
          aria-controls='navbarNav'
          aria-expanded='false'
          aria-label='Toggle navigation'
        >
          <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
        </button>
        <ul class='nav-menu'>
          <li class='menu-active'>
            <Link className='' to='/'>
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link className='' to='/dashboard'>
              Picks
            </Link>{' '}
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link className='' onClick={this.logout} to='/'>
              Logout
            </Link>{' '}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
);
return (
  <div>
    {isAuthenticated ? loggedIn : notLoggedIn}
  </div>
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* nest conditional operators, though readability arguably decreases. For example, if you create a fragment `adminLoggedIn` similar to the `loggedIn` and `notLoggedIn`, and you have a `isAdmin` boolean variable, you can use the syntax:

```
return (
  <div>
    {
      isAdmin
        ? adminLoggedIn
        : isAuthenticated
          ? loggedIn
          : notLoggedIn
    }
  </div>
);
```

You might prefer to avoid the conditional operator, though:

```
return (
  <div>
    {
      (() => {
        if (isAdmin) return adminLoggedIn;
        if (isAuthenticated) return loggedIn;
        return notLoggedIn;
      })()
    }
  </div>
);
```